# How to change script to save attachments by file name instead of by sender name?

Tags: powershell, outlook, email-attachments

I'm using the script below.  It works well to save attachments by sender name in a specified folder.  However, if the sender names are constant, it only saves 1 of the attachments vs. all of the attachments.  I'm assuming it's a write error.  How do I update the script below to save all attachments meeting the filtered criteria by their actual attachment name instead of sender name.

```
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$f = $n.PickFolder()
$filepath = "c:\test"

$f.Items| foreach {$SendName = $_.Sendername
$_.attachments|foreach {
$_.filename
If ($_.filename.Contains("pdf")) {
$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath "$SendName.pdf"))}}}`
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can you not simply use `$_.filename` instead of `$sendname`?

Answer (score 2):

So Lets Follow the rabbit hole here.

We can go to the [Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook/object-model), and look for [Attachments Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments) because we see you are iterating over attachments:

```
$_.attachments|foreach
```

We see in the page:

> Contains a set of Attachment objects

So we go look at the [Attachment Object Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment), look at Properties and we see there is a property for [FileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.filename)

So to send by attachment name we can do this:

```
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$f = $n.PickFolder()
$filepath = "c:\test"

$f.Items| foreach {
    $FileName= $_.FileName
    $_.attachments|foreach {
        $_.filename
        If ($_.filename.Contains("pdf")) {
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath "$FileName"))
        }
    }
}
```